# Selenium WebDriver findElement(By.xpath()) not working for me

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver

I've been through the xpath tutorials and checked many other posts, hence I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I'm simply trying to find the following element by xpath:

```
<input class="t-TextBox" type="email" test-id="test-username"/>
```

I've tried many things, such as:

```
element = findElement(By.xpath("//[@test-id='test-username']"));
```

The error is `Expression is not a legal expression`.

I'm using Firefox on MacBook

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Locating Elements https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
element = findElement(By.xpath("//*[@test-id='test-username']"));
element = findElement(By.xpath("//input[@test-id='test-username']"));
```

(*) - means any tag name.

Answer (score 4):

You should add the tag name in the xpath, like:

```
element = findElement(By.xpath("//input[@test-id='test-username']");
```

Answer (score 3):

your syntax is completely wrong....you need to give findelement to the driver

i.e your code will be :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebeElement element ;

element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@test-id='test-username']");
```

// your xpath is: `"//[@test-id='test-username']"`

i suggest try this :`"//*[@test-id='test-username']"`

Answer (score 2):

You missed the closing parenthesis  at the end:

```
element = findElement(By.xpath("//[@test-id='test-username']"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just need to add `*` at the beginning of xpath and closing bracket at last.

```
element = findElement(By.xpath("//*[@test-id='test-username']"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use contains too:

```
element = findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains (@test-id,"test-username")]");
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified what kind of html element you are trying to do an absolute xpath search on. In your case, it's the input element.

Try this:

```
element = findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='t-TextBox' and @type='email' and @test-    
id='test-username']");
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct `Xpath` syntax is like:

```
//tagname[@value='name']
```

So you should write something like this:

```
findElement(By.xpath("//input[@test-id='test-username']"));
```