# Selenium tests fail on remote machine for chrome and ie drivers

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

I am using selenium grid with testng for distributed testing.
I want to run tests on remote machine on chrome and IE browsers. But the tests fail with exception on these two browsers. When tests are run on Firefox, the run is successful.

Here is the code used for initializing browsers:

```java
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setBrowserName("chrome");
cap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL),cap);
driver.get(myURL);
```

The browsers are successfully initialized. The tests fail while finding element and sending keys.
The code which finds element is :

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath(Xpath_Username)).sendKeys("abc");
```

I am using my machine as hub and another machine as node. Node is connected to hub using below command :

```sh
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role webdriver -hub http://*myip*:4444/grid/register -port 8989 -browser browserName="chrome",version=ANY,platform=VISTA,maxInstances=5 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=D:\chromedriver.exe -browser browserName="internet explorer",version=ANY,platform=VISTA,maxInstances=2 -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=D:\IEDriverServer.exe
```

I am executing tests parallel using testng on different machines and browsers.
The output of the tests :

```java
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.068 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
remoteTest(testproject.testclass)  Time elapsed: 2.313 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 13 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: hostname, ip: 'ip', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version
ntCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: f3667158-1a65-4c24-866a-3d1c5444918b
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//input[@id='login']}
Command duration or timeout: 214 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: 'unknown', time: '2015-07-30 11:02:44'
System info: host: 'hostname', ip: 'ip', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version
criptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: d93bfa55-13b2-427f-b11d-fca5417a0d91
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//input[@id='login']}
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:138)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:445)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:358)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:340)
        at testproject.Browser.login(Browser.java:44)
        at testproject.testclass.remoteTest(testclass.java:10)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 13 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'hostname', ip: 'ip', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version
ntCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: f3667158-1a65-4c24-866a-3d1c5444918b
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//input[@id='login']}
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: 'unknown', time: '2015-07-30 11:02:44'
System info: host: 'hostname', ip: 'ip', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:445)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:358)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:340)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.findElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.findElement(EventFiringWebDriver.java:185)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElement.call(FindElement.java:48)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElement.call(FindElement.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


Results :

Failed tests:
  testclass.remoteTest:10->Browser.login:44 ? NoSuchWindow Unable to find elemen...

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] There are test failures.

Please refer to D:\svn_workspace\SeleniumGrid\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 08 14:45:39 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 38M/260M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please provide any solution to this.

Comment: Check this post 
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952514/selenium-webdriver-findelementby-xpath-not-working-for-me>

Comment: The problem is not with elements. It is with internetexplorer remote driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got solved by adding below code :

```
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
```

Also, Protected mode must be enabled in Internet Explorer and it should be same for all zones.

Answer (score -3):

element = findElement(By.xpath("//*input[@id='login'"));

Comment: Please read the question carefully. Problem is not with finding elements. It is with IE driver when run on remote machine. Tests are run successfully in firefox browser.