# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable when trying to click "datepicker"

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, selenium-webdriver

The relevant HTML

```
<div id="datepickerbox" class="ym-gbox-left">
 <div class="datepick_label">
  <div id="datepicker" class="hasDatepicker">
   <div class="ui-datepicker-inline ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" style="display: block;">
```

My code

```
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH('//*[@id="datepicker"]')).click()
dateWidget = self.driver.find_element(By.ID("ui-datepicker-div"))
rows = dateWidget.find_element_by_tag_name("tr")
columns = dateWidget.find_element_by_tag_name("td")
for cell in columns: self.driver.findElement(By.LINK_TEXT("20")).click()
```

The error I'm getting

```
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH('//*[@id="datepicker"]')).click()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Presumably one of `find_element` or `XPATH` or `click` is a string, so you can't call it.

Comment: @kevin: I know one of them is causing problem, but how do i rectify/correct it???

Comment: Iit seems it should be `self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="datepicker"]').click()`, pass By.XPATH as an argument, don't try to call it

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I tried self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,('//*[@id="datepicker"]')).click() but i get this "No Such Element" error

Comment: Then your xpath is probably wrong

Answer (score 5):

According to the [“Location elements” section](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html) of the manual, `By.XPATH` seems to be a string, and the correct usage would be this:

```
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="datepicker"]')
```

That also makes sense from the error message, since you are calling `By.XPATH`. And the [current source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/common/by.py) also confirms this.

Unfortunately, the Selenium API is not really consistent across different platforms. The syntax you are using, calling `By.xpath()` is used by Java, and in C#, you also have to call `By.Xpath()`. So it’s just naturally that you get confused when you see other examples where it’s being called and in Python, you suddenly need to pass it. So you shouldn’t blindly trust examples you find on the internet (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952514/selenium-webdriver-findelementby-xpath-not-working-for-me)) but always check for which language they are. And check the documentation and/or the source in doubt.

Comment: I tried self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,('//*[@id="datepicker"]')).click() but i get this "NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="datepicker"]"}"

Comment: Then you’re closer to the truth. It works now, but there is no element that matches that XPath string.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the generic `find_element()` method - pass two arguments - the `By` locator type and the locator value:

```
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="datepicker"]')
```

Though, it would be cleaner to use the specific `find_element_by_xpath()` method:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="datepicker"]')
```

And, even cleaner in this case would be to use "by id" locator:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id("datepicker")
```

Comment: I have tried all the above suggested ways and i ended up here

Comment: @kumar are there any `iframe` elements on the page?

Comment: there is no iframes in this web page

Comment: @kumar then, you might need to wait for the datepicker to become present assuming that your locator is correct. See http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits.

Comment: i tried this: self.driver.implicitly_wait("20")
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(('//*[@id="datepicker"]')).click()         still no luck

Answer (score 0):

So what I've found out from this error, is that sometimes a website will load a frame, which by printing the html -> `print(driver.page_source)` will give you what the driver can "see". If you can't find your element in page source, then there's your problem.

I fixed this by finding a .php link inside of the frame element and then adding that link to the current url, here's an example: Given `www.site.com/login` print the page source, and, *if this is the issue*, there will be a .php link that's inside the frame (ex. `/loginPage.php`. Click the link, copy it and execute the `.get([new url])`. This took me to an identical page, but you're able to access your html elements like normal!

Edit: Thank you Stephen for showing me the ropes to adding `code` for the first time!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, removing a bracket is what worked for me.

```
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH('// [@id="datepicker"]')).click()
```

To:

```
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="datepicker"]').click()
```

Comment: This was already suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32616963/18145256) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32617050/18145256).