# Python 'str' object is not callable message when call my function using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

So i try to implement simple `login` to website:

**Driver**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


class Driver(object):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Drive\\chromedriver.exe")
    WebDriverWait30Seconds = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    WebDriverWait60Seconds = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
    WebDriverWait120Seconds = WebDriverWait(driver, 120)

    def close(self):
        """
        close the webdriver instance
        """
        self.driver.quit()

    def navigate(self, url):
        """
        navigate webdriver to different pages
        """
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get(url)
```

**LoginPage**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as expected_conditions

from Driver import Driver


class LoginPage(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.user_name_textbox = Driver.WebDriverWait120Seconds.until(
            expected_conditions.visibility_of(By.ID("login_email")))

    def get_user_name_textbox(self):
        return self.user_name_textbox
```

**Main**

```
from Driver import Driver
from LoginPage import LoginPage

driver = Driver()
driver.navigate("http://blabla.co.il")

logingage = LoginPage()
logingage.user_name_textbox.send_keys("test")
```

And got this error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/myscript/Main.py", line 7, in
> <module>
>     logingage = LoginPage()   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myscript\LoginPage.py", line 10, in
> __init__
>     self.user_name_textbox = expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located(By.ID("login_email"))
> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'str' object is not callable when trying to click "datepicker"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616558/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-when-trying-to-click-datepicker)

Comment: I want to user expected_conditions

Comment: So what?! You're using `ID` as method while it's just a string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`By.ID` is `str` (simply `'id'`) instead of a callable function.

In your case, `visibility_of_all_elements_located` asks for a locator which comes in tuple like

```
self.user_name_textbox = Driver.WebDriverWait120Seconds.until(
    expected_conditions.visibility_of(driver.find_element_by_id('login_email')))
```

Comment: I try this: def __init__(self):
        self.user_name_textbox = Driver.WebDriverWait120Seconds.until(
            expected_conditions.visibility_of(By.ID("login_email"))) anf still same error

Comment: @DeanMovy but you can't call `By.ID` because it is simply not callable... should be `expected_conditions.visibility_of((By.ID, "login_email"))`

Comment: After change to self.user_name_textbox = Driver.WebDriverWait120Seconds.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of(By.ID, "login_email")) i got this error: __init__
    expected_conditions.visibility_of(By.ID, "login_email"))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were give

Comment: @DeanMovy `( ( By.ID, "login_email" ) ) ` two bracket **each** side, it is a tuple of two

Comment: self.user_name_textbox = Driver.WebDriverWait120Seconds.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of((By.ID, "login_email"))) --> still not working

Comment: @DeanMovy OK seems `visibility_of` does not agree with tuple locator. Updated in my answer that you use a driver to find specific element to be visible