# Selenium WebDriver findElement(By.xpath()) get value of this element

Tags: java, selenium

Part of it look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="recaptcha-token" value="Need This Value">
```

I'm running Selenium like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("[@id=\"recaptcha-token\"]"));
```

How I can get "Need This Value" from running this code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver findElement(By.xpath()) not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952514/selenium-webdriver-findelementby-xpath-not-working-for-me)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Selenium Web Driver to retrieve value of a HTML input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852287/using-selenium-web-driver-to-retrieve-value-of-a-html-input)

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, you can first get the element like so:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='recaptcha-token']")); // Any element with that id

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='recaptcha-token']")); // More specific to your tag
```

And then you get the attribute you want using `getAttribute(String attrName)`.

A one-liner would then be:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='recaptcha-token']")).getAttribute("value");
```

If you only want to look for an element with that id, you could simplify that call by using `By.id()` instead of `By.xpath()`:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("recaptcha-token"));
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16955672/6923568) specifically for the `By.xpath` portion of the answer,